# how to find whether wcf 4.0 is installed or not

Tags: .net, wcf

Is there any registry key which i can look for wcf 4.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this [blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/setup/detection-keys-for-net-framework-4-0-and-visual-studio-2010/) on how to detect .NET 4.0 - if you have .NET 4.0, you have WCF 4.0

```
Key     HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Client
Name    Install
Type    REG_DWORD (32-bit integer)
Data    0x00000001 (1)
```

WCF is part of the "client profile" of .NET 4.0 - so this would be a check for WCF 4.0 (seems there are some more advanced WCF features which are not part of this - unfortunately, I don't know for sure what those are).

Find more on the .NET 4 client profile in this [MSDN library article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/client-profile).

If you need to detect the full .NET 4.0 (not just the client profile) check this:

```
Key      HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full
Name    Install
Type    REG_DWORD (32-bit integer)
Data    0x00000001 (1)
```